# Css style not applying to table

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

I have a table that doesn't seem to take certain styles, whether they are in external stylesheet or embedded.

I added a script inside of the head tag and then styled the selector h4 still inside of the head tag.

These aren't applying to the h4 sections within the actual table and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I also have in an external stylesheet a main selector that is supposed to add background color outside of the table and it isn't doing that. 
but it is also not applying to the table.

[image]

Comment: Better to show code as text format rather than image.

Comment: does the external stylesheet work for the other component (not the table)?

Comment: it's easier if you copy/paste the code here. makes it easier to read and tweak ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your `h4` being unable to style is because

```
<h4><th>hello world</th></h4>
```

```css
h4 { color: red; }
```

```html
<h1>Table 1</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <h4><th>Firstname</th></h4>
    <h4><th>Lastname</th></h4>
    <h4><th>Age</th></h4>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `h4` should be inside of your table header

```
<th><h4>hello world</h4></th>
```

```css
h4 { color: red; }
```

```html
<h1>Table 2</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><h4>Firstname</h4></th>
    <th><h4>Lastname</h4></th> 
    <th><h4>Age</h4></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the h4 tag inside the td tag

Your code:

```
<h4><td>The Fantastic Four</td><h4>
...
<h4><td>The Avengers</td><h4>
...
<h4><td>Justice League</td><h4>
...
```

Try:

```
<td><h4>The Fantastic Four</h4><td>
...
<td><h4>The Avengers</h4><td>
...
<td><h4>Justice League</h4><td4>
...
```